# Changing Links in button based on slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider, and the slider outputs a value from 500 to 1600 with a step of 100. I also have a "Go" button, and I would like the link within the Go Button to change based on the value the slider shows. Here is My Code.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
#slidecontainer {
  width: 50%;
  /* Width of the outside container */
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
}


/* The slider itself */

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Override default CSS styles */
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Specified height */
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Grey background */
  outline: none;
  /* Remove outline */
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
  transition: opacity .2s;
}


/* Mouse-over effects */

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}


/* The slider handle (use webkit (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and moz (Firefox) to override default look) */

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Slider handle height */
  background: #4CAF50;
  /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Slider handle height */
  background: #4CAF50;
  /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Cursor on hover */
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <header>
    <h2>Choose Budget</h2>
  </header>
  <div id="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="500" max="2500" value="500" step="100" class="slider" id="myRange">
  </div>


  <ul class="Slider">
    <li>
      <p>Price Point: $<span id="demo"></span></p>
    </li>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="button style3">Go</a>
    <br>
  </ul>

</section>
```

Now, I already am outputting a value, "demo". I now want each value, to correlate to a link, and that link be placed within the "go" button. Thank you for reading.
(also, I am very very new to javascript, so please try to explain it as if I am 4 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do exactly like you change the value of **demo** but you change the attribute **href** instead of the html content.

Let's assume you have a link for each value you may try using `if else` like this :

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var link = document.getElementById("link");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value



// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  if(this.value==500)
    link.setAttribute('href','link1');
  else if(this.value==600)
    link.setAttribute('href','link2');
  else
    link.setAttribute('href','link3');
  /* you do the same for the other values */
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <header>
    <h2>Choose Budget</h2>
  </header>
  <div id="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="500" max="2500" value="500" step="100" class="slider" id="myRange">
  </div>


  <ul class="Slider">
    <li>
      <p>Price Point: $<span id="demo"></span></p>
    </li>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="button style3" id="link">Go</a>
    <br>
  </ul>

</section>
```

or you may consider using an object where you store all links like this

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var link = document.getElementById("link");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

const links = {500: "link1", 600: "link3",700: "link4",800: "link2"};

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  link.setAttribute('href',links[this.value]);
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <header>
    <h2>Choose Budget</h2>
  </header>
  <div id="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="500" max="2500" value="500" step="100" class="slider" id="myRange">
  </div>


  <ul class="Slider">
    <li>
      <p>Price Point: $<span id="demo"></span></p>
    </li>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="button style3" id="link">Go</a>
    <br>
  </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: Ok, so when I run the default it takes me to /500. Im a little confused on how I change the /500 to a specific html file, or the /600, /700, etc. (they all need to be different links)

Comment: I don't think i can provide a link, as I'm running it locally, so i just get an error that says "Not allowed to load local resource: website/500"

Comment: @NoThankd you need to change **link1** **link2** etc with the links you want, and using the if else each link will be correlated with a value

Comment: Oh, and i don't have the url page made up yet, but lets pretend its 500.html

Comment: so you just put `http://500.html` to repalce **link1** and you do the same for the other

Comment: @Xufox am totaly right with you, but he's still learning JS, so better start with easy stuffs

Comment: @Jonasw i agree, but i just want to show him the logic he can implement using simple things, after that we may consider optimization

Comment: @Xufox am gonna update my answer to put different methods

Comment: I would use Xufox's idea if I knew how. I have gotten it to work with the "500.html" "600.html", etc. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh man `{ 500: "http://localhost/500.html", 600: "http://localhost/00.html", .. }` seriously?

Comment: @Jonasw yes but we are obliged to write them all using `if else` or `switch` or an object. I saw he wants the links to have the same names as values (so we can optimize) but it's wasn't clear at the begging so i considered the general case

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:
1) change the links href dynamically. For that the link needs to have an id:

```
<a href = "http://example.com/500.html" id="go" > GO </a>
```

So now we can get that link inside js:

```
const go = document.getElementById("go");
```

And whenever the input changes, we not only update the output but also the link:

```
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  go.href = `http://example.com/${this.value}.html`;
}
```

2) get the sliders value when the linked is clicked. For that, the link does not need to be a link, but can rather be a button:

```
<button id = "go" > GO </button>
```

So when thats clicked, lets redirect to the url containing the sliders value:

```
document.getElementById("go")
  .onclick = e => 
     location.href = `http://example.com/${slider.value}.html`;
```

Things you might want to lookup that ive used :

`const` : a cool and new version of `var`

`${...}` : a *template literal*, basically a way to embed code into strings

`=>` : thats an arrow function ( they work exactly like `function` however i think theyre more readable)

Comment: Buttons shouldn’t act like links and vice-versa…

Comment: @xufox says who? The  page wont be more barrier free with a regular link either.

Comment: It’s bad usability. If I want to open a link in a new tab, I just middle-click. With buttons, this won’t work. Semantics matter in HTML. This is discussed a lot.

Comment: @xufox yeah thats why 1) is first ;)

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so easily. Very helpful!

Comment: @nothankd youre welcome ;) at a certain reputation level ( im not shure if youve reached that yet ) you can upvote helpful answers ( just saying ;))

Comment: i did up vote yours, but I was below 15, so it doesn't show unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

As you’ve said, you’re already outputting the value `this.value` in `output.innerHTML`. Similarly, you can find your link and change its `href`.

There are two ways of finding your link (among others):

- Either use `document.querySelector("a.button.style3")` or a similar selector,
- or give that link an ID (e.g. `<a id="goButton" href="#" class="button style3">Go</a>`), then use `document.getElementById("goButton")`.

Then, to change its `href`, you could

- Set its `href` attribute: `document.getElementById("goButton").setAttribute("href", this.value + ".html")`,
- or its `href` property: `document.getElementById("goButton").href = this.value + ".html".

---

The full code could look like this:

```
slider.oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("goButton").href = this.value + ".html";
}
```

The resulting URL will look like this: `https://yoursite.com/500.html` for a price of $500.